# StorageSharedKeyCredential - Cannot set property of 'accountName' of undefined

Tags: node.js, azure, npm

I've been following the tutorial for creating the azure blob service client for the npm package "@azure/storage-blob" inside the [documentation](https://azuresdkdocs.blob.core.windows.net/$web/javascript/azure-storage-blob/12.0.0/index.html#create-the-blob-service-client). I'm using the alternative method of using the storage account's account name and key to generate a "StroageSharedKeyCredential" object but I'm getting an error where the package is trying to assign the account name to an undefined object.

I've taken my account name and key from the "Settings" -> "Access keys" tab in the azure portal but can't see where I'm going wrong. If anyone can point me in the right direction on what I should check or change it would be greatly appreciated.

Snippet of my code trying to create the StorageSharedKeyCredentialObject

```
const azureAccount = 'some_account_name';
const azureAccountKey = 'some_account_key';
let azureSharedKeyCredential = StorageSharedKeyCredential(azureAccount, azureAccountKey);
```

Snippet below taken from node_modules/@azure/storage-blob/dist/index.js

```
    function StorageSharedKeyCredential(accountName, accountKey) {
        var _this = _super.call(this) || this;
        _this.accountName = accountName;//<---- line reporting the undefined object
        _this.accountKey = Buffer.from(accountKey, "base64");
        return _this;
    }
```

Comment: Should you use maybe `new StorageSharedKeyCredential()`?

Comment: You're right @junnas, I was missing 'new', I think it's time for me to start revising OOP again, thank you

Comment: Hi @Kyle_LK , glad to know your issue has been solved . I have provided codes and samples for your scenario , pls click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in to mak it as an answer so that it will help others who has similar issue . If you have any further queries , pls feel free to let me know . Have a nice day .

Answer (score 0):

I can repro your issue , as @juunas said,  you should use `new StorageSharedKeyCredential(account, accountKey);`

Try code below to get all blobs in a container to have a test , it works perfectly for me:

```
const { BlobServiceClient, StorageSharedKeyCredential } = require("@azure/storage-blob");

const account = "<your storage name>";
const accountKey = "<storage key>";
const containerName = "<container name>";

const sharedKeyCredential = new StorageSharedKeyCredential(account, accountKey);
const blobServiceClient = new BlobServiceClient(
  `https://${account}.blob.core.windows.net`,
  sharedKeyCredential
);

async function main() {
const containerClient = blobServiceClient.getContainerClient(containerName);

let i = 1;
let iter = await containerClient.listBlobsFlat();
for await (const blob of iter) {
  console.log(`Blob ${i++}: ${blob.name}`);
}}

main();
```

Result :

[image]